# pip install rpy2 fails

Tags: python, r, pip

I tried to install rpy2 using

`pip install rpy2`

The error below occured. I also tried downloading it from Github and installing it by running the setup. Interestingly--same errors.

Searching around and trying to understand more of it I have to give up. Any suggestion how to make sure the installation is done cleanly?

I use Python 3.7.3 and 3.6.0 on Windows 10

```
Collecting rpy2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8d/7c/826eb74dee57e54608346966ed931674b521cf098759647ed1a103ccfa79/rpy2-3.0.4.tar.gz
    ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: warning: no previously-included files found matching 'setup.pyc'
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'yacctab.*' found under directory 'tests'
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'lextab.*' found under directory 'tests'
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'yacctab.*' found under directory 'examples'
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'lextab.*' found under directory 'examples'
    zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
    pycparser.ply.__pycache__.lex.cpython-37: module references __file__
    pycparser.ply.__pycache__.lex.cpython-37: module MAY be using inspect.getsourcefile
    pycparser.ply.__pycache__.yacc.cpython-37: module references __file__
    pycparser.ply.__pycache__.yacc.cpython-37: module MAY be using inspect.getsourcefile
    pycparser.ply.__pycache__.yacc.cpython-37: module MAY be using inspect.stack
    pycparser.ply.__pycache__.ygen.cpython-37: module references __file__

    Installed c:\users\lenovo~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-brzevm8p\rpy2\.eggs\pycparser-2.19-py3.7.egg
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\lenovo~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-brzevm8p\rpy2\.eggs\cffi-1.12.3-py3.7-win-amd64.egg\cffi\cparser.py", line 294, in _parse
        ast = _get_parser().parse(fullcsource)
      File "c:\users\lenovo~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-brzevm8p\rpy2\.eggs\pycparser-2.19-py3.7.egg\pycparser\c_parser.py", line 152, in parse
        debug=debuglevel)
      File "c:\users\lenovo~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-brzevm8p\rpy2\.eggs\pycparser-2.19-py3.7.egg\pycparser\ply\yacc.py", line 331, in parse
        return self.parseopt_notrack(input, lexer, debug, tracking, tokenfunc)
      File "c:\users\lenovo~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-brzevm8p\rpy2\.eggs\pycparser-2.19-py3.7.egg\pycparser\ply\yacc.py", line 1199, in parseopt_notrack
        tok = call_errorfunc(self.errorfunc, errtoken, self)
      File "c:\users\lenovo~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-brzevm8p\rpy2\.eggs\pycparser-2.19-py3.7.egg\pycparser\ply\yacc.py", line 193, in call_errorfunc
        r = errorfunc(token)
      File "c:\users\lenovo~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-brzevm8p\rpy2\.eggs\pycparser-2.19-py3.7.egg\pycparser\c_parser.py", line 1848, in p_error
        column=self.clex.find_tok_column(p)))
      File "c:\users\lenovo~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-brzevm8p\rpy2\.eggs\pycparser-2.19-py3.7.egg\pycparser\plyparser.py", line 67, in _parse_error
        raise ParseError("%s: %s" % (coord, msg))
    pycparser.plyparser.ParseError: <cdef source string>:23:5: before: blah1

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\LENOVO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-brzevm8p\rpy2\setup.py", line 184, in <module>
        'rpy2': ['doc/source/rpy2_logo.png', ]}
      File "c:\users\lenovo 2019\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\lenovo 2019\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "c:\users\lenovo 2019\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 447, in __init__
        k: v for k, v in attrs.items()
      File "c:\users\lenovo 2019\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 292, in __init__
        self.finalize_options()
      File "c:\users\lenovo 2019\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 739, in finalize_options
        ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
      File "c:\users\lenovo~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-brzevm8p\rpy2\.eggs\cffi-1.12.3-py3.7-win-amd64.egg\cffi\setuptools_ext.py", line 217, in cffi_modules
        add_cffi_module(dist, cffi_module)
      File "c:\users\lenovo~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-brzevm8p\rpy2\.eggs\cffi-1.12.3-py3.7-win-amd64.egg\cffi\setuptools_ext.py", line 49, in add_cffi_module
        execfile(build_file_name, mod_vars)
      File "c:\users\lenovo~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-brzevm8p\rpy2\.eggs\cffi-1.12.3-py3.7-win-amd64.egg\cffi\setuptools_ext.py", line 25, in execfile
        exec(code, glob, glob)
      File "rpy/_rinterface_cffi_build.py", line 546, in <module>
        """ if os.name == 'nt' else ''
      File "c:\users\lenovo~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-brzevm8p\rpy2\.eggs\cffi-1.12.3-py3.7-win-amd64.egg\cffi\api.py", line 112, in cdef
        self._cdef(csource, override=override, packed=packed, pack=pack)
      File "c:\users\lenovo~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-brzevm8p\rpy2\.eggs\cffi-1.12.3-py3.7-win-amd64.egg\cffi\api.py", line 126, in _cdef
        self._parser.parse(csource, override=override, **options)
      File "c:\users\lenovo~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-brzevm8p\rpy2\.eggs\cffi-1.12.3-py3.7-win-amd64.egg\cffi\cparser.py", line 347, in parse
        self._internal_parse(csource)
      File "c:\users\lenovo~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-brzevm8p\rpy2\.eggs\cffi-1.12.3-py3.7-win-amd64.egg\cffi\cparser.py", line 352, in _internal_parse
        ast, macros, csource = self._parse(csource)
      File "c:\users\lenovo~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-brzevm8p\rpy2\.eggs\cffi-1.12.3-py3.7-win-amd64.egg\cffi\cparser.py", line 296, in _parse
        self.convert_pycparser_error(e, csource)
      File "c:\users\lenovo~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-brzevm8p\rpy2\.eggs\cffi-1.12.3-py3.7-win-amd64.egg\cffi\cparser.py", line 325, in convert_pycparser_error
        raise CDefError(msg)
    cffi.CDefError: cannot parse "blah1 ReadConsole;"
    <cdef source string>:23:5: before: blah1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\LENOVO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-brzevm8p\rpy2\
```

Comment: Solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882477/rpy2-install-on-windows-7) may help.

Comment: In case you still have that issue, apparently there is something wrong with that rpy2 version. At least according to [this](https://github.com/theislab/anndata2ri/issues/21) github issue, 2.9.4 and 3.1.0 should be installable.